# How to fix "DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets"?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, py2exe, python-3.8

### The issue:

So, after compilation, inside the dist folder, there is "PyQt5.Qt.pyd" file,
but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 8, in __load
ImportError: (DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: The specified module could not be found.) 'Z:\\Project\\dist\\PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyd'
```

I am pretty sure that that this **"Qt"** folder from **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt"**, which after compilation is converted to **"PyQt5.Qt.pyd"** file I guess, is responsible for this error. Because when I add this location to my Windows PATH: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin"**, the compiled program works flawlessly.

---

### My temporary fix is:

I copied the "Qt" folder to the "dist", and made a batch script that adds ".\dist\Qt\bin" to PATH, for the current CMD window...Just so I can send it to my client to test it out for now...But this is far from the final solution... What to do?

(I have also tried to copy just "bin", or "platform\qwindows.dll" from "Qt" to dist, but no luck...)

I would appreciate any help or advice regarding this. Thanks in advance!

---

### My info:

**OS info:**
Windows 10 x64, Python 3.8.6 x32

**pip freeze:**

```
altgraph==0.17
cachetools==4.1.1
fbs==0.9.0
future==0.18.2
macholib==1.14
pefile==2019.4.18
Pillow==8.0.1
 py2exe==0.10.0.2
PyInstaller==3.4
 PyQt5==5.15.1
PyQt5-sip==12.8.1
pywin32==228
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
six==1.15.0
```

**py2exe setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script":"main.py"}], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["PyQt5.Qt","PyQt5.sip","PyQt5.QtWidgets","PyQt5.QtCore", "PyQt5.QtGui"]}})
```

Comment: I ended up using the "pyinstaller"...Anyway, thanks for the answer @Soos Erno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy all dll's from PyQt5\Qt\bin to dist, except the ones beginning with Qt5* (You might not need d3dcompiler_47, libEGL, libGLESv2 and opengl32sw if your not using direct3d or opengl)

I suggest you try out to run your application converted with py2exe on a newly installed windows (maybe in a virtual machine) to find out if it has other dependencies.

**Update:** Actually, I only needed to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019, without copying any dll files. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0